# Displaying a multiline text field with appended text in customized form

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp, powerapps-forms

I am working with a SharePoint Online site collection, I have a customized form for a list created using Power Apps. The comments field is multiline with appended text. I want to display all of the comments when the form is in view mode.

I know I need to pull the versions of the item, which I can do with a Power Automate Flow, but that is rather slow. What is the best practice for showing all the comments for such a field in a customized form?

Comment: No need to use the Power automate flow. Check this video: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=hzLEecSpmFo. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: That's a different direction. But thanks.